# How to change the text color of a Text View using onclick(), using button?

Tags: java, android

## ***ANSWERED***

What I want to do is change the text color of a text view on a button press using onClick().
In my layout file, there's one text view and 2 buttons with android:onClick="onClick" attribute.

This is my code:

---

```
package ic.lunar.tictactoefree;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(Button b){
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
    if(b.getId()==R.id.grey){
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    if(b.getId()==R.id.white){
        tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
}
```

---

now whenever I click any of the 2 buttons, the app force closes.
What to do to make it work.
I want to get the color changed according to the button pressed.

Comment: post your `settings.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
public void onClick(View v){ // method signature
```

Assuming you have buttons in settings.xml

```
android:onClick="onClick"  // for buttons in xml
```

Initialize in onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
}
```

And

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId())
    {
       case R.id.grey:
           tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       break;
        case R.id.white:
           tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
       break;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Thanxxx. This worked well.
I had Already added android:onClick="onClick"

Comment: Can You help me in getting this done dynamically across activities.
Like user would press the button in settings activity and the text color will get changed in main activity and also that it should not revert back to original color until user clicks another color button or else till he restarts the app.

Comment: @LunarInc. you can't you need to pass a value like boolean then start MainActivity and then retrieve the boolean value and check if its tru change text color in MainActivity else default.  Each activity has its ui and lifecycle

Comment: IF menu is used?
users can access menu>Settings>Text Color from any activity?

Comment: @LunarInc. first to set color to text view you need to infalte the layout. at a time only one activity is displayed. So how do you plan to change the textview color a activity that is not displayed on screen

Comment: 1st let me clear it what I exactly wanna do.
My game is a Simple Tic Tac Toe Game.
There's a table layout with 9 buttons in 3X3 format.
I have set 2 different colors for Cross and circle,1 each.
But what I want is to let users choose from several colors before starting the Game.

Comment: @LunarInc. you need to use settings. us preferences in oncreate of the required activity read the preference and set the color to textview

Comment: Thank-you for your help and support.